# C# - Add node to serialized class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm very new to C# and please excuse me if i'm asking you stupid question.
I don't know how to add node to serialized class.

Here is my code:

```cs
namespace DuloGames.UI
{
    [Serializable]
    public class UISpellInfo
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public Sprite Icon;
        public string Description;
        public float Range;
        public float Cooldown;
        public float CastTime;
        public float PowerCost;
        public float test;

        [BitMask(typeof(UISpellInfo_Flags))]
        public UISpellInfo_Flags Flags;
    }
}
```

Here is how i try add new node to the serialized class above from another class:

```cs
using DuloGames.UI;

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void AddToNode()
    {         
        UISpellInfo serializedNode = new UISpellInfo();
        serializedNode.Add(new UISpellInfo()
        {
            ID = 1,
            Name = "test",
            Description = "description"
        });
    }
}
```

This is how i try to add new node to the serialized class but it seems i'm not doing it correctly. Can you please help me out ?

Comment: "add new node to" ... something that doesn't have nodes? What are you trying to do? Why are you saying "serialized class"? There's no serialization other than that word in your question. You need to clarify what you're asking about here.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "add new node to" and "serialized class"

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your are trying to do but you `UISpellInfo` class is just a POCO that has no `Add` method right?

What are you trying to do.. I think you need to have a `List` of UISpellInfo object before you can add something to it?

```
List<UISpellInfo> nodes = new List<UISpellInfo>();
nodes.Add(new UISpellInfo{ID = 1, Name = "test", Description = "description"});
```

This should work i think.

But then again what will you do with serializedNode, i don't see you are doing anything with it?